# Why do I not get notice that files are renamed from FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have some code that watches the file system for changes and updates a container of file representations. All works for the most part, until you rename a directory. I would expect to get a rename event for all the files and subfolders of the renamed directory since they have new paths, but I only get a single message that the parent directory has changed names. Is there an event i've forgotten, or a flag that needs set? Currently I'm handling the directory rename and iterating through my collection to update the files to the new name, but I feel like there should be something in place to receive a notification for each file instead.

My setup:

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(item.Path);
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
watcher.Created += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(OnMediaCreated);
watcher.Deleted += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(OnMediaDeleted);
watcher.Changed += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(OnMediaChanged);
watcher.Renamed += new System.IO.RenamedEventHandler(OnMediaRenamed);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think one usually consider the contained files to be changing if the container changes it's name. Which would be why you don't get an event for the contained files.

May I suggest that you create a double-linked tree-representation of the directory structure, so that each file and directory knows of the container it is in. Then make a ToString() override in the file representation that traverses your tree to the root to build the display-string.

When you get your directory rename event you can find the directory in your representation and trigger an update for each of the files leafing out from this branch.

That way you won't have to loop through things, but rather use recursion, if that seems more elegant to you.

Also, note that FileSystemWatcher has a buffer overflow issue you might wanna check out so you don't loose events.

Comment: I like your idea, but in my structure, directorys are not represented. Only files are shown. It's a listbox, so I do some grouping on parts of the file path to list contents by directory. That works fine. Then, if a user renames a directory, my files do not update anymore because they are still binded to the old path (since they didn't get a rename event). I suppose I'm going to have to continue to manually go through the items and force updates myself.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for a start, please use consistent terminology within the post. You've mentioned directory, folder, and file almost interchangeably. For the sake of discussion I'll drop this down to folders and files. From what you describe you are watching a folder which contains files and possibly sub-folders. You rename the folder, and you are expecting media renamed events for all of the files (and sub-folders if applicable) to be raised as well? No, I don't believe you will get them.

The FileSystemWatcher hooks in to watch the contents of a folder, not the folder itself. You can verify this behaviour by hooking to a folder and renaming the folder then renaming an item within the folder. (and displaying the full path of the change) you will notice that the path of the renamed item retains the original folder name. Renaming the folder does not invalidate the watcher, but it doesn't catch the event either. However, if you have a sub-folder under the watched folder, with a file under it, and rename the sub-folder and it's child file, the full path of the child will reflect it's parent folder's name change. Kind of hard to describe but: (IncludeSubdirectories = true)

```
Folder1 (watched)   
  File1   
  Folder2
    File2
```

Renaming Folder 1 then file 1. Folder1's name change is not detected, and no, file 1 won't fire a change either. It's name didn't change. Renaming File1 after Folder1's name change will still show "Folder1" as the path.
Renaming Folder2 will be detected and report back the new name. renaming File2 after Folder2 was renamed will be detected and File2's full path will show the updated Folder2 folder name.

If you want to detect renames to the watched directory then what you actually need to do is watch the directory level above it with a Filter set to the directory you're actually interested in. Either use one FSW with IncludeSubdirectories, or two filesystem watcher, one watching the folder, and another for it's contents. When the folder change is detected, update your external references with the folder name change as necessary, then re-initialize the content watcher one so that path names are returned correctly.

Comment: I apologize. I didn't have much time to proof read as I was on my way out of work when I posted this and wanted to quickly get my question up. You correctly understand what I wanted to do. Here is the reason I assumed you would get the message for each file in the directory as well as the directory: I bind some text and an image to the file paths, so when they directory is renamed, those bindings then fail. The image is trying to reference the old path, so things fail. The basic issue is that files don't know the directory was renamed, so I have to do work to update all those paths.

Comment: What if the parent of the Folder1 gets renamed? Where do you stop monitoring parents? Not to mention that all the events fired for the files are still giving you the wrong old path. The FileSystemWatcher is seriously flawed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable your FileSystemWatcher object to Include subdirectories.

```
watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
```

Comment: That's already on. The issue isn't that I'm not getting any message it's just that the files in my container aren't getting any message to update when their path has changed due to a directory rename.